# ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js

Tags: angular

I'm pretty new to Angular and when trying to buid the app (ng build) I get this:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js
Module build failed: Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, read
at Object.readSync (fs.js:568:3)
at tryReadSync (fs.js:353:20)
at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:382:19)
at Storage.provideSync
```

Any Idea of how can I buld my app?

Thank you in advance!